# Different kind of concatenate two arrays in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two lists posted from view to controller such as

```
int[] blablaIds = { 13, 377, 1002 };
int[] secondBlaBlaIds = { 7, 18, 126 };
```

For some reason I want to explicitly combine these as

```
int[] combinedIds = { { 7, 13 }, {18, 377}, {126, 1002} }
```

Is it possible with LINQ?

Comment: Does the ordering matter?

Comment: You're presenting this in a *really* confusing way, showing indexes in square brackets in the first part, then values in square brackets in the second. Why bother with indexes at all in the first part, and why bother with square brackets at all in the second?

Comment: It's also not at all clear what you mean by `[7] [13]` for example. That's two numbers... how are you expecting to combine them into a single element?

Comment: ordering of course matters basically 7 is the first array's first item and 13 is the second arrays first item.

Comment: So how long is the output, and what are the elements? A [mcve] would make life *much* simpler here.

Comment: Okay, so you've clarified the *input* arrays slightly, although it would still be a lot simpler if you just posted valid code that would create them. You haven't clarified the *output* array at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet output number may dynamically change but the number of items count always be equal between these two arrays.

Comment: Please see what existing questions about https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+concatenate+array suggest and explain why Concat or Zip don't work for you. So far post looks like author may not even tried to search for solutions (that could bring plenty of downvotes due to "does not show any research") - which probably not true, but very hard to see author's extensive research from the post in its current state.

Comment: I don't know how many more ways I can find to ask you to clarify what the output array should contain. What does `[7] [13]` mean? Is it 713? Is that actually meant to be two elements, 7 followed by 13? Something else? Again, if you provide a [mcve] showing what you've tried so far, expected output and actual output, you're much, much more likely to get help. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: (I'd also suspect that this has nothing to do with ASP.NET - certainly nothing you've shown so far indicates a connection with it. The [mcve] should ideally be a console application for the sake of simplicity, unless you believe your question really *is* ASP.NET-specific.)

Comment: @maccettura: Your edit has *assumed* a lot about what the OP wants. In particular, you've converted the output array from having three confusing elements into six straightforward elements. How did you work out that's what the OP meant? Rolling back, for the OP to clarify.

Comment: (I've edited the question to resolve the bit that we *do* understand, i.e. what the input arrays look like. But it's still unclear what the output array is meant to be.)

Comment: From the OP's earlier edit: _"Sorry for the confusion.Basically 7 is the first item of first array and 13 is the first item of second array and it goes on."_.  It seemed implied to me that he meant for the [0] index of the second array to be first, then the [0] index of the first array, then repeat.  The output the OP showed followed that pattern.

Comment: @maccettura: The "first array" and the "second array" are the *inputs* as far as I'm aware. That much is clear. But your edit changed the *output* array, which is what the OP still hasn't clarified at all. We know where the values are coming from, but not what `[7] [13]` means. Is that meant to be two elements of the output array, as you assumed, or is the aim to combine them? The OP hasn't provided enough information to say.

Comment: @JonSkeet Given `x = { 13, 377, 1002 }` and `y = { 7, 18, 126 }` with the expected output `z = { 7, 13, 18, 377, 126, 1002 }` is it not fair to assume that pattern?  Especially with the OP's quote?  I agree this question is super confusing, just trying to help the OP by playing detective.

Comment: @maccettura: Where did you get "with the expected output `z = { 7, 13, 18, 377, 126, 1002 }` from though? That has 6 elements in the array - the OP has 3 unspecified elements: `{ [7] [13], [18] [377], [126] [1002] }`. (Note the two commas, not five.) Playing detective is one thing - editing the question to *assume* you know what the OP means when they're being very unclear doesn't help them though. Unfortunately the OP seems to have decided to abandon the question (no response in the last quarter of an hour) so we may never know.

Comment: @JonSkeet oh jeez, I am an idiot.  I did not notice the lack of commas.

Comment: @JonSkeet I should combine them as first item of the newly created array [7] [13] in which 7 stands for first item of the first array which is going to be combined into new array and 13 stands for seconds array first item which is going to be combined with 7. and it so on. I could not explain it better apologies for my english.

Comment: @user3055125 when you say "combine them" do you mean add them together?  Make them a key value pair?

Comment: @user3055125: So each pair ends up as a new array? That's not going to be a `long[]` or an `int[]` then - it'll be a `long[][]` or an `int[][]`. Note that if you'd followed my advice and shown this as a [mcve], the English part wouldn't have mattered... but `[x] [y]` isn't how an array is represented in C#. If you'd written `{ { 7, 13 }, {18, 377}, {126, 1002} }` it would have been clearer, although then the return type wouldn't have worked. But maybe that's not what you mean at all.

Comment: I could be way off base here, but the way I read it, he wants to take 2 single dimension arrays and combine to a two dimension array where 0,0 is the 0 item in the first array and 0,1 is the 0 item in the second array etc.

Comment: @maccettura yes exactly.

Comment: @user3055125 Yes to what?  I asked two distinct things

Comment: @JonSkeet actually I have expected to be put in a right direction. and yes I have to convert long to int to be able to add them together.

Comment: @user3055125: Well how were we meant to guess you wanted to add them together? If you'd written `7 + 13` that would have been clear. `[7] [13]` has *nothing* to do with addition...

Comment: @maccettura I meant add them together.

Comment: Please edit your question to make this clear, so that it will be reasonable to add an answer.

Comment: Do you meant **add** them together as in a math sum, for example 1+1=2?  Or **combine** them into a structure, for example { 1, 1 }.

Comment: @maccettura combine them into a structure as you demonstrate.

Comment: @JonSkeet safe to edit now?

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited my question.

Comment: Right. Do you understand that "add them together" and "create a new array with the two elements" are *entirely different operations*? And that the result you're talking about *won't* be a `long[]` or `int[]`?

Comment: Yes I understand now. I should convert the result to int[].

Comment: But how? What would the elements be? And what would you do with `long` values which weren't in range of `int`? It's hard to believe that it's *still* unclear what you're trying to achieve here...

Comment: I need this. int[] combinedIds = { { 7, 13 }, {18, 377}, {126, 1002} };

Comment: If you want an `int[]` you will potentially **lose precision**.  `int` represents a a 32 integer, `long` is 64 bit.  One of your arrays is a `long[]`, meaning you wont be able to represent a number larger than "2,147,483,647" if you want the final output to be of type `int`

Comment: @user3055125: No, you don't need that, because that doesn't make sense. You've said on the left hand side that you want a one-dimensional integer array: `int[] combinedIds`. Then on the right hand side you've given something which *isn't* a one-dimensional integer array: `{ { 7, 13 }, {18, 377}, {126, 1002} };`. That's like saying you want `string text = 10;`. It just doesn't work from a type system perspective - and that's before we get to the potential loss of information when casting from `long` to `int`.

Comment: @JonSkeet so, as final answer should I give it a try of Jesse Carter's suggested approach.

Comment: It seems to me that the first thing you should do is actually work out your requirements. You seem unsure of them at the moment - and it's pointless and frustrating trying to provide someone code when they don't know what they want. Next time, please be clear in your mind what you're trying to achieve before asking. Bear in mind that if you continue to ask poorly-received questions, you will be automatically banned from asking any more until you've improved existing ones. Stack Overflow is a great resource - don't waste it by writing ill-prepared questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as a list of `long or int` you're going to have to pick one and then convert the other list to the correct datatype. Once they're the same datatype you can easily concat the two lists.

```
longIds.Concat(intIds.Cast<long>());
```

As Jon Skeet has identified in the comments your question is incredibly difficult to answer in its current form. If you're looking to create a paired list of items from the first and second you could try using .Zip. You're still going to have to do some casting if you want ints and longs to coexist in the same collection. Here's an example (not verified with IDE).

```
var zipped = firstIds.Zip(secondIds, (first, second) => new List<long> {first, (long) second});
```

Comment: I don't think that's the sort of concatenation the OP wants - they're not being very clear, admittedly, but I don't think this does what the OP wants.

Comment: Yeah agreed, looking at it now it seems he might want a Zip based operation as the output appears to pair elements of the first with the second...

Comment: I suspect so too, although until the OP has clarified their output, it's going to be hard to provide a real answer :(

Comment: At first, sorry for the inconvenience. I did not think my question would cause that much confusion. Thank you for the answer. Your offer sounds quite sensible to me. I will try and find out.

Comment: Not that it answers the OP's question but, couldn't you use a list of tuple<int, long> to preserve the types.

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx). It's rather powerful and should provide the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: It's not at all clear how you expect `SelectMany` to be used here, particularly as it only deals with a single input sequence. The question is unclear to start with, but providing an unclear answer doesn't help that.

Comment: Good point. Getting down voted by Jon Skeet will definitely be the low point of my day.